# How to pause another script for a few seconds in linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

How can I execute the specified script for the specified number of seconds, suspend the script for the same number of seconds, and continue this cycle until the script is finished?
1st script would function as a controller for the 2nd script.

Comment: Seems like this is a popular exam or homework question currently. And as always: you should not post such questions here. Solve them yourself, you will never learn anything otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the PID of the 2nd script. This can be done by the correct usage of ps command.
After that, you can suspend and continue the script with the following commands, sending the correct signals:

```
 kill -STOP PID
 kill -CONT PID
```